# What is the answer for "Mary ____ to the USA before last year"?

Tags: word-choice, tense, negation

> Mary...........to the USA before last year.
> (has been, had been, hasn't been, hadn't been)

I know that the answer is "hadn't been" or "had been".
But what is the ***exact*** answer of the question?

Comment: what do you mean by "exact"? do you want us to choose either "had been" or "hadn't been"? both are grammatically correct, and which one you want depends on whether or not Mary had been to the US before last year...

Answer (score 1):

Had been/ had not been refers to past perfect tense construction.

Based on your syntax, past perfect tense construction completes the sentence, and makes most sense

> Mary had not been to USA before last year.

When Mary went to USA last year, that was her time.

> Mary had been to USA before last year

Her trip to USA last year, was not her first trip.

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer is **had been/ had not been** because the past perfect is used when events happened in the past. As we are pointing to an event which happened a year back, hence the usage.
Whereas has been/ has not been usage would have been inappropriate because **has been** is supposed to indicate action that began at some time in the past and is still in progress.